# Retrieve the required JSON object from JSON response

Tags: java, json, class, model

I am trying to connect to a remote service to receive some JSON data. I would like to model the JSON in an efficient way so that I can deserialise it to a corresponding Java class model.

Say that the JSON I receive is of the format

```
{
 {
   "name" : "abc",
   "age" : 54,
   "gender" : "m",
 },
{
   "name" : "def",
   "age" : 45,
   "gender" : "m",
 },
{
   "name" : "der",
   "age" : 43,
   "gender" : "f",
 },

}
```

**Here are my questions**

- Is there any way to get the details of a person (say name = "abc") without Iterating over the response ?

> If not can you suggest any other JSON format which enables us to quickly access any value
> from the response without Iterating.

- If Iterating is the only way, then could you also suggest the effective way to model the class and the JSON

Comment: If you want direct access you should use a Map. You have to define your entity and when you generate the response of the server create a Map<String, entity> where the string is the name. Then the json representation of each entity will be { "abc": { "name": "abc", "age": 43, "gender" :"f"}}. You could decide not to serialize the name if it's going to be the key of the map, but it might be handy to get the complete entity.

Comment: The JSON you provided is not actually valid, so there is pretty much no way to parse it.

Comment: Yeah, collections are wrapped using [ and]. Also you don't append a comma after the last element of an object

Comment: Thanks for identifying the JSON format and your suggestions. 
@EduardoPérez Do you mean changing the JSON format to { "abc": { "name": "abc", "age": 43, "gender" :"f"}} and deserialise to Map<String, Some_Entity >

Comment: @ShanmukhaVoruganti Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: it is suggested to get familiar with https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath